# Prerendered tiles of small area?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik

I would like to use custom styled tiles for quite a small area. I know there are general solutions like mapnik or mapbox but since I am really only interested in showing tiles for one forrest, is there a way to pre-render those and but the resulting png's on a static assets-server?

How would you go about this? Setup a local OSM-Server, crawl mapnik for that area and dump the data yourself? Or is there a tool/cli-option for this particular use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest ways would be either using Tilemill (works standalone and offline) or QGIS with the QTiles plugin. Both allow you to render your tiles.

Comment: An easy other way/software for small area could also be [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/) (basically it allows you to render tiles from an OSM extract without the "extraction in database" step).

Comment: Thanks for the tilemill-tip! For anybody else here trying to do the same thing: export as MBTiles and then use [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to convert that to simple png's that can be directly accessed via leaflet or something like that